# Sorting list of lists not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am trying to sort the following list of lists:

```
var entries = [[new Date("Thu Apr 06 2017"), 12], [new Date("Thu Feb 02 2017"), 11]]
entries.sort()
```

I expect that the entries will switch order, since the first date comes after the second. However, this is not happening. Why is this?

Answer (score 4):

You will need to provide an argument to `sort()` so that it knows how to compare the inner arrays. By default it will just convert them to a string and compare them

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

> If compareFunction is not supplied, elements are sorted by converting them to strings and comparing strings in Unicode code point order. For example, "Banana" comes before "cherry". In a numeric sort, 9 comes before 80, but because numbers are converted to strings, "80" comes before "9" in Unicode order.

So in your case its comparing `"[new Date("Thu Apr 06 2017"), 12]"` to `"[new Date("Thu Feb 02 2017"), 11]"` In which case `A` in Apr comes before `F` in Feb

Working code:

```
var entries = [[new Date("Thu Apr 06 2017"), 12], [new Date("Thu Feb 02 2017"), 13]]
entries.sort(function(a, b) {
   // compare the dates
   return a[0]-b[0];
});
```

Comment: your sort is not symmetrical you dont have `sort(a, b) === -sort(b, a)`, because you return only 0 (false) and 1 (true) and no negative value.

Answer (score 0):

The sort() method sorts the items of an array.

The sort order can be either alphabetic or numeric, and either ascending (up) or descending (down).

By default, the sort() method sorts the values as strings in alphabetical and ascending order.

You can sort like this

```
var entries = [
    {calander: "Thu Apr 06 2017",value:"12"}, 
    {calander: "Thu Feb 02 2017",value:"11"}
];

entries.sort((x)=> new Date(x.calander).getTime());
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running your function with the order of the  elements of the array switched in the beginning? Also, the OP has an array of arrays and you have an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

As your array contains array within array.[new Date("Thu Apr 06 2017"), 12] in main array is subarray that contains date and 12 numerical entry.
So sorting whole array you need to write your own custom sort function.
It is so simple as your date object contains

```
  [new Date("Thu Apr 06 2017"), 12]
  [0]->new Date("Thu Apr 06 2017")
  [1]->12
```

So sort your array according date you need write your sort function as like below.

```
entries.sort(
          function(x, y)
          {
             return x[0] > y[0];
          }
        );
```

it will sort your array according date.

Answer (score 0):

To sort an array in javascript you are using the [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method.

When this method is called without arguments, `arr.sort()` then

> the array is sorted according to each character's Unicode code point value, according to the string conversion of each element.

Which does not work for your case, since you have arrays inside your array.

Therefore you want to use the form `arr.sort(compareFunction)`, where you need to provide a `compareFunction(a, b)` which compares two elements of your array. The compare function needs to return a number. If less than zero, `a` comes first, if zero they are the same, if higher than zero, `b` comes first.

So to solve your problem, we just need to create the compareFunction which compares the inner arrays of your array.

```
var entries = [[new Date("Thu Apr 06 2017"), 12], [new Date("Thu Feb 02 2017"), 11]]

function compareMyArrays(a, b){
  var aTime = a[0].getTime();
  var bTime = b[0].getTime();
  return aTime - bTime;
}

entries.sort(compareMyArrays);
```